# Best way to include Bootstrap in project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm just beginning to learn Bootstrap and was wondering what the best way to include it in a project is. Should I download the link off the website or use a cdn link directly in my code? If cdn, where should I be using the links from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you believe those accessing your website will always have access to the internet then use the CDN. This is the case with the vast majority of projects.

If your project might be installed on a network that does not have access to the internet then download bootstrap and host it with your site.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use CDN, you should put it before `</head>` tag on every page, or put the links on a file and call it on every pages.

Answer (score 0):

If not going to use a CDN, you could try the package manager Bower. Helps with page load speed.

> http://bower.io

Answer (score 0):

Download the source files that way your IDE can tell you if you have made any errors. Downloading from the CDN wont enable you to do that.